# Using an Offset in Excel's Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, offset, conditional-formatting

I am trying to add a conditional format formula for cell A1.  I would like to change the color to green when the offset value (2,20)=True.  I can't use `=$U$3=TRUE` because the range will change as I copy and paste this to other tabs.

Would it be possible to input into the formula something like this?

```
=ActiveCell.Offset(2,20)=True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
=OFFSET(A1,2,20)
```

No need for the `= TRUE` part.

Make sure the cell reference isn't absolute and nor is the range it is applied to.

[image: Conditional formatting rule]

Applied:

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you.  That was driving me crazy, I only knew how to do that in VBA.

Comment: one more thing, what if I wanted to have a requirement to only fill in the color when both cells =OFFSET(A1,2,20) AND =OFFSET(A1,2,21) as true?

Comment: Never mind, I wasn't able to get it to work using the and function, but I figured it out using the following: =(OFFSET(A1,2,20))*(OFFSET(A1,2,21))